# squaring a very large BigInteger is very slow

Tags: clojure

I'm working through 2022's Advent of Code and I'm on [Day 11 part 2](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/11).

I have this solution:

```
(ns advent-of-code-2022.day11
  (:require [taoensso.timbre :as log]))

(declare give-monkey-item)
(defrecord Monkey [items operation throw-item num-inspections])

(defn create-monkey [items operation divisor monkey-true monkey-false]
  (->Monkey
    items
    operation
    (fn [item monkeys]
      (if (= (mod item divisor) 0)
        (give-monkey-item item monkeys monkey-true)
        (give-monkey-item item monkeys monkey-false)))
    0))

(defn give-monkey-item [item monkeys catcher]
  (update-in monkeys [catcher :items] #(conj % item)))

(defn throw-items [monkeys current-monkey]
  (reduce (fn [monkeys item]
            (-> item
                (biginteger)
                ((.operation current-monkey))
                ((.-throw_item current-monkey) monkeys)))
      monkeys
      (.items current-monkey)))

(defn adjust-current-monkeys-inspections [monkeys current-monkey-index]
  (let [current-monkey (get monkeys current-monkey-index)
        num-items (count (.items current-monkey))]
    (update-in monkeys [current-monkey-index :num-inspections] #(+ % num-items))))

(defn clear-current-monkeys-items [monkeys current-monkey-index]
  (let [current-monkey (get monkeys current-monkey-index)
        itemless-monkey (assoc current-monkey :items [])]
    (assoc monkeys current-monkey-index itemless-monkey)))

(defn play-turn [monkeys current-monkey-index]
  (let [current-monkey (get monkeys current-monkey-index)]
    (-> monkeys
        (throw-items current-monkey)
        (adjust-current-monkeys-inspections current-monkey-index)
        (clear-current-monkeys-items current-monkey-index))))

(defn play-round [monkeys]
  (reduce (fn [monkeys monkey-index]
            (play-turn monkeys monkey-index))
          monkeys
          (range (count monkeys))))

(defn play-rounds [monkeys num-rounds]
  (reduce (fn [rounds round-number]
            (log/info round-number)
            (let [latest-monkeys (last rounds)]
              (conj rounds (play-round latest-monkeys))))
          [monkeys]
          (range num-rounds)))

(defn calculate-monkey-business [monkeys num-rounds]
  (let [rounds (play-rounds monkeys num-rounds)]
    (->> (last rounds)
         (map #(.-num_inspections %))
         (sort)
         (reverse)
         (take 2)
         (reduce *))))
```

I'm testing it using this code:

```
(ns advent-of-code-2022.day11-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [advent-of-code-2022.day11 :refer :all]))

(def monkeys
  [(create-monkey
     [54 98 50 94 69 62 53 85]
     (fn [old] (* old 13))
     3 2 1)
   (create-monkey
     [71 55 82]
     (fn [old] (+ old 2))
     13 7 2)
   (create-monkey
     [77 73 86 72 87]
     (fn [old] (+ old 8))
     19 4 7)
   (create-monkey
     [97 91]
     (fn [old] (+ old 1))
     17 6 5)
   (create-monkey
     [78 97 51 85 66 63 62]
     (fn [old] (* old 17))
     5 6 3)
   (create-monkey
     [88]
     (fn [old] (+ old 3))
     7 1 0)
   (create-monkey
     [87 57 63 86 87 53]
     (fn [old] (.pow old 2)) ; this is slow for big numbers
     11 5 0)
   (create-monkey
     [73 59 82 65]
     (fn [old] (+ old 6))
     2 4 3)
   ])

(deftest day11-full-test-part2
  (testing "day11-full-test-part2"
    (is (= (calculate-monkey-business monkeys 10000) 10605))))
```

This tries to run for 10000 iterations, but around the 200th iteration the marked function `(fn [old] (.pow old 2))` in the test code starts squaring very large BigIntegers and gets extremely slow.  It is so slow that the program would probably take a few days to finish.  If I replace `.pow` with a simple `+`, the program completes in a few seconds.  `.pow` is the latest function I've tried; I started with a simple `(* old old)` and tried `clojure.math.numeric-tower/expt` as well, but all three have this problem.

Is there a way to square these large BigIntegers efficiently in Clojure?

Comment: The answer below is helpful but in general, when you hit BigIntegers, efficiency of the calculations will drop dramatically. My hint is to avoid them, especially in AoC. This particular challenge can be solved differently without using big numbers at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alan Thompson has some advice that will speed up your program a little. I doubt it will be as much as 1000x - for small numbers, it would probably be more like 100x compared to un-hinted `.pow`, and 2x compared to `(* x x)` - but even if it were, this will not be close to enough of a speedup to save you. In fact, as I will show in a moment, speed is not your only limiting factor!

You note that things get slow around the 200th iteration out of 10000, and predict a few days' running time. But you're looking at a process with *exponential* running time, and people tend to grossly underestimate how big an exponential formula will get. So I predict you will need a real algorithmic change, not just some fairy dust to sprinkle on the existing algorithm.

Why do I say it's exponential? Well, you have observed that the dominating factor is operations of the form `x = x * x`: squaring a number and then moving on. Of course because of all the monkey business not every round will involve squaring all the numbers, but that's what will dominate in making your numbers large. Imagine ten thousand rounds of just writing `x = x * x`, starting with an innocuous number like 2. You square 2 (2^1), then square the resulting 4 (2^2), then square the resulting 16 (2^4), then square the resulting 256 (2^8), and so on, squaring ten thousand times. That process computes 2^(2^10000): clearly exponential (in fact, superexponential, because the exponent itself grows exponentially).

Why is this a problem? Well, storing the exact binary representation of a number like 2^(2^10000) in your computer's memory is simply impossible. Storing such a number's exact binary representation anywhere in the entire universe is impossible: there's not nearly enough atoms to make up all the bits. Of course, I've overestimated by assuming that each round involves squaring the number; but you can expect around 20% of the numbers to be squared each round, because the monkey who tests for divisibility by 5 throws to the monkey who squares. This is still far outside the realm of possibility.

So any approach that uses a BigInteger to store the exact representation of this number is unworkable. Fortunately, there are some easy improvements to make that will let you perform this simulation lightning fast. I don't want to give away the whole thing, since much of the fun is solving the problems yourself. Here are a few hints, spoilered individually.

> You don't need the exact values themselves at the end of the process.

> You don't need the exact values *during* the process either

> All you need is to tell whether they're divisible by some primes

> Isn't it rather nice they never ask you to divide by something?

> Have you considered modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

Try a type-hint in case your code is using reflection to find the correct `.pow` method to run.  It can make a 1000x difference in speed:

```
(fn [old] (.pow ^BigInteger old 2))
```

You can also set this:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
```

which will print a warning when reflection is required, for example:

```
Reflection warning, tst/demo/core.clj:9:23 - call to method pow can't be resolved (target class is unknown).
```

Here is an example timing:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.math :as math]
    ))

(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(defn math-pow-plain [arg] (Math/pow arg 2.0))
(defn math-pow-hint [arg] (Math/pow ^Double arg 2.0))

(defn pow-plain [arg] (.pow arg 2))
(defn pow-hint [arg] (.pow ^BigInteger arg 2))

(def two-bi  (biginteger 2))
(defn mult-hint [arg] (.multiply ^BigInteger arg arg ))

(verify
  (let [p 6
        N (math/pow->Long 10 p)
        base-dbl  12345678901234567890.0
        base-bi (biginteger 12345678901234567890)]
    (print "math-pow-plain   ")
    (time
      (dotimes [i N]
        (math-pow-plain base-dbl)))
    (print "math-pow-hint   ")
    (time
      (dotimes [i N]
        (math-pow-hint base-dbl)))
    (newline)
    (print "pow-plain  ")
    (time
      (dotimes [i N]
        (pow-plain base-bi)))
    (print "pow-hint   ")
    (time
      (dotimes [i N]
        (pow-hint  base-bi)))
    (print "mult-hint  ")
    (time
      (dotimes [i N]
        (mult-hint  base-bi)))
    )
  )
```

with results:

```
*********************************************
*************** Running tests ***************
:reloading ()

Testing tst._bootstrap

-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.11.1    Java 19.0.2
-----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
math-pow-plain   "Elapsed time: 0.661787 msecs"
math-pow-hint   "Elapsed time: 0.66835 msecs"

pow-plain  "Elapsed time: 1939.324816 msecs"
pow-hint   "Elapsed time: 68.920437 msecs"
mult-hint  "Elapsed time: 19.201765 msecs"

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

Passed all tests
Finished at 23:17:34.914 (run time: 2.038s)
```

Build using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

We can get more accurate results using [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [criterium.core :as crit]
    [tupelo.math :as math]
    ))

<snip>


    (newline)
    (prn :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------)
    (println "math-pow-plain   ")
    (crit/quick-bench
      (math-pow-plain base-dbl))
    (newline)
    (prn :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------)
    (println "math-pow-hint   ")
    (crit/quick-bench
      (math-pow-hint base-dbl))
    (newline)
    (prn :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------)
    (println "pow-plain  ")
    (crit/quick-bench
      (pow-plain base-bi))
    (newline)
    (prn :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------)
    (println "pow-hint   ")
    (crit/quick-bench
      (pow-hint base-bi))
    (newline)
    (prn :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------)
    (println "mult-hint  ")
    (crit/quick-bench
      (mult-hint base-bi))
```

with results:

```
:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
math-pow-plain   
Evaluation count : 54186174 in 6 samples of 9031029 calls.
             Execution time mean : 5.959432 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 2.325416 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 4.152295 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 9.127577 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 6.671950 ns

:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
math-pow-hint   
Evaluation count : 54730104 in 6 samples of 9121684 calls.
             Execution time mean : 6.400439 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 2.262171 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 4.824092 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 10.093095 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 6.671950 ns

Found 1 outliers in 6 samples (16.6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (16.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 81.8856 % Variance is severely inflated by outliers
```

and

```
:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
pow-plain  
Evaluation count : 290466 in 6 samples of 48411 calls.
             Execution time mean : 2.445839 µs
    Execution time std-deviation : 326.407836 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 2.121704 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 2.838628 µs (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 6.671950 ns

:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
pow-hint   
Evaluation count : 7890228 in 6 samples of 1315038 calls.
             Execution time mean : 79.168431 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 10.776154 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 71.917202 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 96.642962 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 6.671950 ns

Found 1 outliers in 6 samples (16.6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (16.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 31.7716 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers

:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
mult-hint  
Evaluation count : 24351408 in 6 samples of 4058568 calls.
             Execution time mean : 22.017819 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 4.678650 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 18.117006 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 29.207411 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 6.671950 ns

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

So we see that `math-pow-plain` and `math-pow-hint` are both 6 ns (nanoseconds) per call for Double values.  For BigIntegers, `pow-plain` is about 2400 ns/call compared to 80 ns/call for `pow-hint`, about a 30x penalty.  Using `mult-hint` is about 22 ns/call about a 4x speedup over `BigInteger/pow`.  Not nothing, and may be  worthwhile in a tight loop.  Only timing can tell.

Note that you can help to trace down slow parts of your program using the [tupelo/profile](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/23.03.04/api/tupelo.profile)
library.

Comment: The advice to type-hint is fine, and will obviously speed up the code in the Question by some large factor. But I have a couple nits to pick. First, note that your results, as well as the javadoc for Math/pow, make it obvious there's never a need to typehint its arguments; the compiler will just discard those hints. Second, your `mult-hint` is doubling, while everything else is squaring, do you're not comparing equals. Last, the question says that `(* x x)` is also slow, but that should never be *much* slower than the most efficient thing, and certainly won't do reflection. I'd look deeper.

Comment: Sorry! Cut/paste error.  I changed it from `(.mult arg 2)` to `(.mult arg arg)` and the timing is the same.